# MongoDB count not matched with document real count

Tags: mongodb

I inserted a number of 1M data

But `db.Data.count()` command return `1411000`

but below command return `1000000`

```
db.Data.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$mallId",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: {$sum: "$count"}
        }
    }])
```

and `db.Data.getDistribution()` command return

```
Totals
 data : 450.8MiB docs : 1411000 chunks : 10
 Shard atlas-80djc9-shard-0 contains 20.87% data, 21.26% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 328B
 Shard atlas-80djc9-shard-2 contains 35.02% data, 35.43% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 331B
 Shard atlas-80djc9-shard-1 contains 44.1% data, 43.3% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 341B
```

Why are they different?

What is the right count?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please answer yourself in the answer section. No answers in the question, please. Accept your answer after you write it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852644/wrong-count-of-documents-in-mongodb-shard-cluster/61862338#61862338

Comment: Having a look at [db.collection.count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) documentation should answer your question